# Lost submit functionalities do JS after jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to using submit post in ajax ( properly jQuery .load() function ) but I have a problem because after the page .load (see below) submit  button >>to .click(function() doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve that?

Here is my entire code:

```
<script src="{$sitepath}/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="newswhite">
    
    <form name="cform0" id="cform0" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="text1" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_comment" class="btn" name="submit" value="comment">
    </form>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
    $("#submit_comment").click(function() {
        var url = "some.php"; 
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#cform0").serialize(),
                success: function(data)
               {    
                $("#newswhite").load(" #newswhite >*");
            //$("#newswhite").html(data);
              }
             });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
```

It all works just once. After .load I have to refresh the page by browser...
Any idea?

Comment: You need to prevent the default form submit process

Comment: Ok, how to do that?

Comment: Easy web search to learn how

Comment: because you replace the form.... that new button is not the button you bound the click to.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#submit_comment", function() { });`

Answer (score -1):

```
Found the answer:

$(document).on("click", "#submit_comment", function() {
```

thanks epascarello - works fine.

Comment: Why did you make this an answer?

Comment: To show the code :)

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: thanks charlietfl for some clue.